# Jquery Click on CSS Class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a button as follows in my html

```
<button class="btn btn-inverse" type="submit">Login</button>
```

So the CSS class name is "btn btn-inverse". How can I perform JQuery click operation with css class ?

This doesn't works for me

```
$('.btn btn-inverse').click(function(){
alert("Called");
});
```

Any Help would be appreciatable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: clcik? :) is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work this way:

```
$('.btn.btn-inverse').click(function(){
    alert("Called");
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3LE4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
'.btn btn-inverse'
```

is looking for an element with a class 'btn' which has a child element 'btn-inverse'. The space means you're now talking about a new (child) element.

In your case you want an element that has class 'btn' and class 'btn-inverse', so you'd want to remove the space and precede the second class 'btn-inverse' with a '.' to represent a class name.

```
'$('.btn.btn-inverse')
```

This way you're talking about the same element with two classes.

Also you want 'click' instead of 'clcik'

Comment: Sorry Guys, It's typo here. $('.btn.btn-inverse').click(function(){
    alert("Called");
}); works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these class selectors to select that element:

```
$('.btn')
$('.btn-inverse')
$('.btn.btn-inverse')
```

The best choice depends on what other elements in the page use those classes and if you want to seleclt them as well.